# Getting an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with Webpack Dev Server on port 8080

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm following the official [webpack tutorial](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/) for setting up webpack dev server. Here is my webpack config:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    print: './src/print.js',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    // port: 8081 // <-- uncommenting this line gets rid of the error
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Output Management',
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
}
```

However, when I try to run the server, I'm getting a weird issue. The code compiles properly according to the webpack output, but when the URL tries to open in Chrome/Safari, I get "This site can’t be reached" with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. In the config above, when I uncomment the `8081` line, everything works as intended (except the server is now on port 8081).

Initially, I thought that the port must be occupied, but found this was not the case, since I can run a file like

```js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

And see the expected `Hello World` on port 8080.

Why is webpack dev server unable to work on port 8080?

If it matters, I'm on OSX 10.15 Catalina with Node.js v12.13.0.

Answer (score 2):

for those who still can not figure this out. I found this link in github which worked really great for me.

Add this to your start script in package.json file

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --host 0.0.0.0 --hot --open --useLocalIp"
```

[this is the link for those who want to read more.](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1347#issuecomment-407008054)

Comment: I changed the computer I used to run my code and then this problem started happening. Thanks. This solved it for me. I still don't understand why though

Answer (score 0):

Using your same configuration works for me. Try checking the port status (there might be something clashing just with webpack) by:

```sh
lsof -i :8080
```

That will list if there is something using it, and if that's the case, take the PID number shown and:

```sh
kill -15 <PID>
```

PD. (This would be a comment but I can't add comments yet).

Comment: Then that means the port is available. Have you tried with another webpack config?

Comment: Yeah, I opened an issue on webpaIck dev server: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2295.Lsof seems to give a different output if the port is 8080 was other ports. There are more lines of output for non-8080 ports. Maybe that means something? There are details in the Github issue.

Comment: It’s really weird . I usually use the port 8080 without issues with a custom webpack config. Perhaps is something related to your computer.

Comment: Yep, and I have no idea where to look for this kind of thing either :/

Answer (score 0):

For me it was ESET that had blocked the port.
You can disabled it under **Preferences -> Web Access Protection -> Enable HTTP** protocol checking (uncheck the checkbox or change the ports).